# Deploy Android App for Beta Testing

Tags: android

Is there a way to deploy a Android App for Beta Testing in Google Play Store, so that Users can download and test the app?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: yes. there is https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deploy your app to the Beta testers on Google Play Sore by creating and uploading signed APK as a `Beta Release` to the `Play Store`.

See below URL for tutorial guide :

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en